# Asp Mvc4 Conditional attributes does not work as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following partial view binded to a view model.

```
@model Omega.UI.WebMvc.Models.InputWithLabelViewModelBase


@{
    string required = null;
}

@if (Model.IsRequired)
{
    {
    required = "required";
    }
}

<td><label id="@Model.LabelId">@Model.LabelText</label></td>
<td>
    <input  id="@Model.InputId" data-bind= "value: @Model.CurrentValueProperty" required="@required"/>
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="@Model.InputId"></span>
</td>
```

When `IsRequired` is true I want the `required attribute` to be available, otherwise not. When I run that code and `IsRequired` is false the `required attribute` is presented with empty value: required="". I am quite new to asp mvc and I do not see what am I doing wrong.

UPDATE per dove`s post:

This does not work:

```
@{
    bool required = Model.IsRequired;
}


<td><label id="@Model.LabelId">@Model.LabelText</label></td>
<td>
    <input  id="@Model.InputId" data-bind= "value: @Model.CurrentValueProperty" required="@required" />
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="@Model.InputId"></span>
</td>
```

This renders the following html:

`required="False"` (if IsRequired is false and vice versa)

which is incorrect:

from the html documentation:

The required attribute is a boolean attribute, and can be set in the following ways:

```
<input required>
<input required="required">
<input required="">
```

Note: I am using Razor 2.0

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Mvc takes works with booleans](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/) in these special cases (assuming required works like checked).   Try this:

```
required="@Model.IsRequired"
```

Can you also check your project references to confirm you are using Razor 2 as your example above should work also.  Right click on System.Web.Razor view the properties and see what Version it is.  It should be 2.0.0.0